# Installation of private repo via composer fails in Github codespaces

Tags: git, github, ssh, composer-php, codespaces

We are creating a codespace for one of our websites. All of our websites need to install code from one of our private repos via composer. According to the codespaces docs https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-your-codespaces/managing-repository-access-for-your-codespaces, all we should need to do is add the private repo to the list in devcontainer.json...

```
        "codespaces": {
            "repositories": {
                "our-organization/private-repo": {
                    "permissions": "read-all"
                }
            }
        }
```

...then codespaces is supposed to pop up with some kind of access dialog after rebuild. When we rebuild, however, we get no access dialog. Then, when we run `composer install`, when the terminal tries to install the package from our private repo, it still complains and demands I create a personal access token. Everyone having to install a temporary personal access token is not a sustainable solution.

Are we required to install ssh keys to connect the private repo and this site's codespace? It'd be much easier if the devcontainer settings worked as described in the documentation. I am not sure what step I am missing.

Comment: X-Ref: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/51851

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSH url for the private repo, try to use HTTPS url instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).